# Why are some if statement rules not working?

Tags: javascript, debugging, if-statement

So in my program, I am trying to push certain values to an array if conditions are met. Even though the conditions are not met for some values, things still get pushed to the array. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Heres the code:

```js
    //This program's purpose is to translate to and from morse code.

    var input, output;      //Declare all global variables.
    var inputArray = [];    //Declare the empty array to store the converted characters.

    input = (prompt('Enter the word(s) or sentence(s) that you wish to convert.', 'Hello friend')).toLowerCase(); //Prompt the user for input and convert it to lowercase.

    function Encode(input) {    //Declare a function to encode characters into leet.
        var i, il;              //Declare all local variables.

        for (i = 0, il = input.length; i < il; i++) {   //Declare a for loop to cycle through each character in the input.

            if (input.charAt(i) === 'a') {              //If the character found at the current position in the input is A,
                inputArray.push('.-');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'b') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is B,
                inputArray.push('-...');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'c') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is C,
                inputArray.push('-.-.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'd') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is D,
                inputArray.push('-..');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'e') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is E,
                inputArray.push('.');                   //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'f') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is F,
                inputArray.push('..-.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'g') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is G,
                inputArray.push('--.');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'h') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is H,
                inputArray.push('....');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'i') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is I,
                inputArray.push('..');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'j') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is J,
                inputArray.push('.---');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'k') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is K,
                inputArray.push('-.-');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'l') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is L,
                inputArray.push('.-..');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'm') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is M,
                inputArray.push('--');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'n') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is N,
                inputArray.push('-.');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'o') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is O,
                inputArray.push('---');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'p') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is P,
                inputArray.push('.--.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'q') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Q,
                inputArray.push('--.-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'r') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is R,
                inputArray.push('.-.');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 's') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is S,
                inputArray.push('...');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 't') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is T,
                inputArray.push('-');                   //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'u') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is U,
                inputArray.push('..-');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'v') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is V,
                inputArray.push('...-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'w') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is W,
                inputArray.push('.--');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'x') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is X,
                inputArray.push('-..-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'y') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Y,
                inputArray.push('-.--');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'z') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Z,
                inputArray.push('--..');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '0') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 0,
                inputArray.push('-----');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '1') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 1,
                inputArray.push('.----');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '2') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 2,
                inputArray.push('..---');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '3') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 3,
                inputArray.push('...--');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '4') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 4,
                inputArray.push('....-');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '5') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 5,
                inputArray.push('.....');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '6') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 6,
                inputArray.push('-....');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '7') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 7,
                inputArray.push('--...');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '8') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 8,
                inputArray.push('---..');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '9') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 9,
                inputArray.push('----.');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '.') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is .,
                inputArray.push('.-.-.-');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '?') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is ?,
                inputArray.push('..--..');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '!') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is !,
                inputArray.push('-.-.--');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === ('(' || ')')) {  //If the character found at the current position in the input is ( or ),
                inputArray.push('-.--.-');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === ':') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is :,
                inputArray.push('---...');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.
            
            else {                                      //If the character found at the current position in the input is not specified above,
                inputArray.push(input.charAt(i));       //The push the same character to the inputArray to signify it has not been converted.
            }                                           //End else.

        }   //End for.
    }       //end function.

    Encode(input);                          //Call the endcoder function.
    output = inputArray.join('');           //Join all converted characters    stored in the array together.
    console.log('Input was: ' + input);     //Log the input to the console.
    console.log('Output is: ' + output);    //Log the output to the console.
```

```html
    <script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Example: When I enter "Hello friend" into the prompt, "...././.-../.-../---/ ..-./.-./.././-./-../" is returned. In the output, the slashes I marked in the brackets are not supposed to be there: "...././.-../.-../---[/] ..-./.-./.././-./-..[/]"

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `(i + 1) != ' '` Why are you comparing a number to a string with a single space? Did you mean `input.charAt(i + 1)`?

Comment: IMO, you have way too much repetition. Create an object, like `var code = {'a': '.-', 'b': '-...', 'c': '-.-.'}` and so on, and then do `code[input.charAt(i)]` to get the mapping from the current character.

Comment: @squint Yes that was it! That seemed to be exactly what I did. I must have overlooked that! Thank you!

Comment: @MattNau This code is _seriously_ [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Heavily consider the idea of creating a character map, like squint mentioned.

Comment: I posted an answer while @squint 's comment hadn't loaded for me. I suggest he/she also post an answer so it can be up-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking for the `(i+1)` value, not the input character at that position.

Replace

```
  if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
            }
```

with

```
  if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
            }
```

everywhere

```js
//This program's purpose is to translate to and from morse code.

    var input, output;      //Declare all global variables.
    var inputArray = [];    //Declare the empty array to store the converted characters.

    input = (prompt('Enter the word(s) or sentence(s) that you wish to convert.', 'Hello friend')).toLowerCase(); //Prompt the user for input and convert it to lowercase.

    function Encode(input) {    //Declare a function to encode characters into leet.
        var i, il;              //Declare all local variables.

        for (i = 0, il = input.length; i < il; i++) {   //Declare a for loop to cycle through each character in the input.

            if (input.charAt(i) === 'a') {              //If the character found at the current position in the input is A,
                inputArray.push('.-');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'b') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is B,
                inputArray.push('-...');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'c') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is C,
                inputArray.push('-.-.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'd') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is D,
                inputArray.push('-..');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'e') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is E,
                inputArray.push('.');                   //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'f') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is F,
                inputArray.push('..-.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'g') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is G,
                inputArray.push('--.');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'h') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is H,
                inputArray.push('....');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'i') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is I,
                inputArray.push('..');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'j') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is J,
                inputArray.push('.---');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'k') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is K,
                inputArray.push('-.-');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'l') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is L,
                inputArray.push('.-..');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'm') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is M,
                inputArray.push('--');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'n') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is N,
                inputArray.push('-.');                  //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'o') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is O,
                inputArray.push('---');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'p') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is P,
                inputArray.push('.--.');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'q') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Q,
                inputArray.push('--.-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'r') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is R,
                inputArray.push('.-.');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 's') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is S,
                inputArray.push('...');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 't') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is T,
                inputArray.push('-');                   //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'u') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is U,
                inputArray.push('..-');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'v') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is V,
                inputArray.push('...-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if ((i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'w') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is W,
                inputArray.push('.--');                 //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'x') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is X,
                inputArray.push('-..-');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'y') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Y,
                inputArray.push('-.--');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === 'z') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is Z,
                inputArray.push('--..');                //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '0') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 0,
                inputArray.push('-----');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '1') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 1,
                inputArray.push('.----');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '2') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 2,
                inputArray.push('..---');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '3') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 3,
                inputArray.push('...--');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '4') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 4,
                inputArray.push('....-');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '5') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 5,
                inputArray.push('.....');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '6') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 6,
                inputArray.push('-....');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
              if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
              }   
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '7') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 7,
                inputArray.push('--...');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '8') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 8,
                inputArray.push('---..');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '9') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is 9,
                inputArray.push('----.');               //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '.') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is .,
                inputArray.push('.-.-.-');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '?') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is ?,
                inputArray.push('..--..');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === '!') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is !,
                inputArray.push('-.-.--');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === ('(' || ')')) {  //If the character found at the current position in the input is ( or ),
                inputArray.push('-.--.-');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.

            else if(input.charAt(i) === ':') {          //If the character found at the current position in the input is :,
                inputArray.push('---...');              //Then push the new character to the inputArray to signify it has been converted.
                if (input.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {                   //If the next character is not equal to a space,
                    inputArray.push('/');               //Then push a / to the inputArray.
                }                                       //End if.
            }                                           //End else if.
            
            else {                                      //If the character found at the current position in the input is not specified above,
                inputArray.push(input.charAt(i));       //The push the same character to the inputArray to signify it has not been converted.
            }                                           //End else.

        }   //End for.
    }       //end function.

    Encode(input);                          //Call the endcoder function.
    output = inputArray.join('');           //Join all converted characters    stored in the array together.
    console.log('Input was: ' + input);     //Log the input to the console.
    console.log('Output is: ' + output);    //Log the output to the console.
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```